# Fastest way to open "This PC"

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I'm used to pressing the <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to open a new window in File Explorer with Computer. Windows 10 changed this to be Quick Access, which isn't useful to me.

How can I change it back to Computer, or what is the fastest way in Windows 10 to open Computer?

Comment: double click on 'This PC" or create a [keyboard shortcut](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2759-pc-shortcut-create-windows-10-a.html) or [this](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/4999-shortcuts-assign-keyboard-shortcut-windows-8-a.html) or just change where explorer opens to by doing [this](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3734-file-explorer-open-pc-quick-access.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should be as simple as doing the following.

> Step 1: Open File Explorer
>
> Step 2: Options -> **Change folder and search options**
>
> [image]
>
> Step 3: Change the setting for `Open File Explorer` from **Quick
>   Access** to **This PC**
>
> [image]
>
> Step 4: Click **Ok**

[Source](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3734-file-explorer-open-pc-quick-access.html)